# Convert string from webservice to LIST

Tags: c#, json, string, web-services

I receive from client a raw string as this:

```
 { "\"wrapper\": {\"system\": { \"session\":\"ed6d1cc6-82f9-46e8-91bb-eae341a771cf\", \"ip\":\"\", \"station\":\"\"},{ \"personal_profile\": {\"suffix\":\"1096\",\"first_name\":\"Varvara\",\"middle_name\":\"\",\"last_name\":\"Terlouw\",\"street\":\"\",\"number\":\"\",\"add\":\"\",\"postal\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"birthday\":\"\",\"relation_type_id\":\"\"}},{ \"personal_contacts\": {\"contact_type_id_0\":\"409\",\"contact_0\":\"06-26096994\",\"contact_0\":\"on\"},{\"contact_type_id_0\":\"420\",\"contact_0\":\"jj@vv.com\",\"contact_0\":\"on\"},{\"contact_type_id_0\":\"\",\"contact_0\":\"\",\"contact_0\":\"on\"}},{ \"personal_work\": {}},{\"personal_connected\": {}},{\"personal_interests\": {}}}} "
```

I get the string in into my webservice and need to convert this to LIST<> so I can process the data to my database, preferable with my classes

Comment: Show your code that doesn't work, and explain what "does not work somehow" means

Comment: Javascript serializer will only work if you have the good structure. when there is a collection you need to create another class and names must match. Your problem with backslashes is that it's an escape character, try replacing using it's char equivalent.

Comment: @Franck that I know, however I did not manage to get them out

Comment: //string dd = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(q).Replace(@"\""", @"""");
    //string ddd = q.Replace(@"\""", @"""");
    //string profile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(q, Formatting.Indented);

Comment: var valueSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>("{\"wrapper\": { \"id\": \"MyID\",\"global\": { \"session\":\"rrrrr\", \"ip\":\"\", \"station\":\"\"}}}").ValueSet;

Comment: ok You are serializing yourself the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here and old example of a class i used a while ago as another example for simple json serialize :

```
internal class CFingerPrint
{
    public string WanIP;
    public string MacAddress;      

    public string getClassEncrypted()
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this);
    }

    public CFingerPrint getClassDecrypted(string sSerializedClass)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CFingerPrint>(sSerializedClass);
    }
}
```

I use the same way to communicate with other languages a lot and haven't had any issue yet except Dates that are problematic in JSON but that's another story.

Edit : example how to use :

```
// create new class
var originalClass = new CFingerPrint();
// fill some data
originalClass.WanIP = "test1";
originalClass.MacAddress= "test2";

// serialize to json string
var classSerialized = originalClass.getClassEncrypted();

// create new class from string only
var newClass = new CFingerPrint().getClassDecrypted(classSerialized);

Console.WriteLine(newClass.WanIP); // output "test1"
Console.WriteLine(newClass.MacAddress); // output "test2"
```

Example with childs :

```
public class Manufacturer
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public List<Motor> AvailaibleMotors{ get; set; }

    public string getClassSerialized()
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this);
    }

    public ManufacturergetClassDeSerialized(string sSerializedClass)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Manufacturer>(sSerializedClass);
    }
}

public class Motor
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public List<Voltage> Voltages { get; set; }
}

public class Voltage
{
    public int Volt { get; set; }
    public int Phase { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
}
```

so manufacturer can have one or many motors which can have one of many voltage and this works perfectly no matter what.

Comment: thanks for sharing how do I call the class?

Comment: @Frank I tried your solution however it returns empty, here is what I use:                                                                    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            q = "{ \"global\": { \"session\": \"ed6d1cc6-82f9-46e8-91bb-eae341a771cf\", \"ip\": \"\", \"station\": \"\" }}";
            string output = jss.Serialize(q);
            CFingerPrint p = new CFingerPrint();
            var global = p.getClassDecrypted(q);

Comment: i edited my answer and added usage example. it's an old class that was originally made as test so method name are wrong i know.

Comment: I am not sure if it will work like that as I have many child in there, but need way to think of to implement functional +1

Comment: a child is simple, each child or array you need to create a class with it's properties like this class. and in the parent you declare a `List<ChildClass> NameOfProperty;` the de-serialization of the parent class go down childs if named properly

Comment: The only thing is I have a raw JSON string in (see header post) and the problem is that I need to convert this good, I will test run with your sample, in my case the "originalClass" is a raw JSON string

Comment: Well then you only have to parse it manually once and not the structure and create the classes and you should be fine.

Comment: Thats a bit of the problem it wont Serialize, however it works like this var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var data = serializer.Deserialize(q, typeof(object)); So try to figure out why it only does it with a dynamic object

Comment: Very cool got the code up and running works like a sun exact what I wanted to have, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this too.

```
public ActionResult jsonPull()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    var json = webClient.DownloadString("example.com/json");
                    var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                    return Json(parsed);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new { json = "error" });
            }              
        }
```

Comment: gives me error illigal character when I put the string in the DownloadString

Comment: what String are you entering? This string needs to be a reachable URL. You are trying to get JSON from online, right?

Comment: I get a raw string from a webservice, which contains backslashes which is not unlogic as somehow I am only able to send this data while using JSON.stringify({ q: json }) on the client in ajax otherwise the string is not accepted in the webservice. So I get the string from my AJAX webservice. Meanwhile using a dynamic object to do this not what I want but it works. Like this var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var data = serializer.Deserialize(q, typeof(object));

Comment: wait, so you do not manually insert a url? Are you debugging and making sure this webservice is returning a valid URL first? What my code above does is go to a URL and pull what should be a json on that page. i.e. `["json":{"name":"bob"}]`. I cannot tell you what is causing the illegal character error if you do not show me a url, or an example url with the same characters/slashes/symbols in it.

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public string DataHandler(string q) This is what I get in sended by ajax webservice, the string is generated on the client this is how I save user input. So I dont use a url just call from client to webservice